# Two problems about Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, characteristic-functions, weak-derivatives

Problem $1 .$ Show that the function $u: B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ defined by
$$u(x)=u\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}\right):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text { if } x_{N}>0 \\
0 & \text { if } x_{N}<0
\end{array}\right.$$ not belong to $W^{1, p}(B(0,1))$ for any $1 \leq p \leq \infty.$

Problem $2 .$ Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be an open bounded set, let $x_{0} \in \Omega,$ and let $1 \leq p<\infty .$ Prove that if $u \in C(\bar{\Omega}) \cap C^{1}\left(\Omega \backslash\left\{x_{0}\right\}\right)$ is such that the (classical)
gradient $\nabla u$ belongs to $L^{p}\left(\Omega ; \mathbb{R}^{N}\right),$ then $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$

For the first question,I have proved that with the dimension $1$, But I cannot  extend my proof to the general case.

For the second problem,I have no idea about it.

Can someone help me solve these  problems?Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 1, show that if it had a weak derivative, the weak derivative would need to be zero a.e., then show that zero cannot be the weak derivative by considering an explicit test function.

Comment: For 2, are you allowed to use the fact that for smooth functions, the classical derivative is equal to the weak derivative? If not, one can show this by integration by parts I believe

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks for your answer first.I know that fact,but I still have no idea about the problem.Can you give me a more detailed hint?

Comment: @User8128 Thanks for your answer first.For the first problem,I choose $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(B^-(0,1))$,Then we get $\int_{B^-(0,1)} v \phi d x=0$, so $ v=0$ a.e. in $B^-(0,1)$,But I cannot get $v=0$in $B(0,1)$.